# How to move through git commits

Tags: git, presentation

I have a linear commit history. I want to use git for presentations.

1. How to get to first commit and move through the history till last in order of making commmits.
2. How to move back and forth between lists.

Comment: Try `git checkout <commit-hash>`. You can see all commit history in `git reflog`

Comment: I have to enter Hash value here. What I want is enter hash value once and move to next commit through some command. `git checkout --continue`

Comment: `git checkout <commit-hash>~<x>` where x is the number of steps back you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the previous commit:

```
$ git checkout HEAD~1
```

Go to the next commit:

```
$ git log --reverse --pretty=%H | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1 | xargs git checkout
```

Here, `--reverse` output the commits chosen to be shown in reverse order.
e.g. `git log -10 --reverse` would get **last 10 commits** then reverse it.

Comment: I'm clearly not understanding the question - isn't this for a presentation? Do people normally bring up a command line and hand-type commands during a presentation?

Comment: Maybe OP prefer to use `terminal` instead of `gitk`.

Answer (score 2):

For a *presentation*?

Why not just use gitk and press 'up' each time?